# Select multiple columns with linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to select multiple columns by using LinqToSql, but I am having a hard time with it. I am quite new in LinqToSql.
When I am selecting 1 column I do it like this:

```
string[] name = mycontext.Users.SingleorDefault(p => p.UserId == 1).UserName;
```

Is there anything similar for multiple columns?
I actually want to assign `Name` and `Surname` in a `ListBox` control

Comment: `var user = mycontext.Users.SingleorDefault(p => p.UserId == 1)` will select the entire User entity for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current request will query the whole user (select *).

In most cases, it is enough and you can access to each column separately :

```
var user = mycontext.Users.SingleorDefault(p => p.UserId == 1);

var userName = user.Username;
var password = user.Password;
// etc...
```

If you only need one (or several columns) but not the whole user, you can do it like this:

```
var userInfo = mycontext.Users.Where(p => p.UserId == 1).Select(p => new {p.UserName, p.Password}).SingleOrDefault();

var userName = userInfo.UserName;
var password = userInfo.Password;
```

If you prefer a collection of string in result, you can do it this way:

```
List<string> userInfo = mycontext.Users.Where(p => p.UserId == 1).Select(p => new List<string> { p.UserName, p.Password }).SingleOrDefault();

var username = userInfo[0];
var password = userInfo[1];
```

This way, the generated query will looks like `Select UserName, Password From UserTable`. Its usefull only if your table has a lots of columns or a heavy one (blob for example).

How it works: by calling the `Where` extension methods firstly, you tell .NET to not run the query immediately. It will be executed on the `SingleOrDefault` call. But at this moment, the query has been completed and the whole part is done in SQL.

Comment: You can't use `,` in the select statement like that you've shown in your answer (`.Select(p => p.UserName, p.Password)`). This is an invalid LINQ statement.

Comment: @fharreau you are right actually, I don't have to select multiple columns from a single table, I can just select the whole table, but as UserObject I cannot create a ListBox with two columns(Name, Surname).
By the way Select(p => p.UserName, p.Password) didn't work either. The compiler shows it as error.

Comment: @S.Akbari : my bad, I forgot to add the new {} for creating an anonymous type :D. Fixed !

Comment: @L.Achilles take a look at the last par of my answer. You can create a list as a result within the `Select` method ! In my tests, It does not work with `string[]`

Comment: @fharreau you are absolutely right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

```
var result = mycontext.Users.Where(p => p.UserId == 1)
                            .Select(c => new {c.UserName , c.Family ,...})
                            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: string[] name = mycontext.Users.SingleorDefault(p => p.UserId == 1)
              .Select(c => new {c.UserName , c.Family ,...});
doesnt seem to work at all, not just for array and tha's also true, multiple columns cannot be assigned to an array like @Rahul said.

Comment: @L.Achilles No. Use var instead of `string[]`.

Comment: @S.Akrabi unfortunately, it still doesn't accept SingleofDefault(p...).Select

Comment: @L.Achilles. if you want to select multiple columns then you can't store them in array. simple ... that's it.

Comment: @Rahul I never said that I want to store them in array. That's your assumption. In my question I showed how I retrieve a single column and I ask how to select multiple columns.

Comment: @L.Achilles Copy and Paste my code. I didn't say `SingleofDefault(p...).Select` I said `.Select(c => new {c.UserName , c.Family}).SingleOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you return User object?

```
var user = mycontext.Users.SingleorDefault(p => p.UserId == 1)
```

After that you can get all properties of User without creating dynamic types

Comment: so how do you create a listbox with User object.
In my last case (single column listbox) I wrote:
string[] names=string[] name = mycontext.Users.SingleorDefault();
foreach(string user in names){
ListItem newItem = new ListItem(names[i]);
ListBox1.Items.Add(newItem);
i++;
}